# Apache and MySQL bringing server to a crawl several times a day

Tags: 12.04, apache2, mysql

I am having difficulty troubleshooting a bottleneck problem with my Ubuntu 12.04 server.

I run a very small intranet website off of the server.  There are web requests (SOAP, HTML, REST, etc) at a pace of several small requests every minute, but all in all the web server isn't worked hard.  The server is only used as a web server and a SMB file server for a handful of users.

About 10 days ago and many times a day since, the server slows to a crawl.  All SMB connections are temporarily dropped, ping requests time out, SSH sessions drop, and the webserver becomes unresponsive.  This "blackout" happens for a period of anywhere from 30 seconds to a few minutes.  Afterward the server catches up, all requests response times and service response times return to normal.

I used atop to narrow the problem down to what appears to be Apache and possibly MySQL pegging the server.  No other processes during the blackout period raise suspicion.  During these blackout periods, the number of Apache processes jumps from 1-4 to 16+ processes.  Each process is taking 5-10% of the CPU, so cumulatively, the CPU is pegged at 100%.  MySQL is also working higher than normal, but is only at about 15% of the CPU.

I have researched the Apache log files (access.log and error.log) for the blackout period  and cannot locate any suspicious or abnormal web requests or problems during that time.  All the requests appear normal just before the blackout as the requests are during normal times.  Of course, during the blackout, no access is logged because the server isn't handling the web requests.

I would think if there were one web request making the server work hard, Apache would still handle all of the others fine, thus keeping the Apache process count only slightly higher.  The 16-20 and higher process count for Apache makes me wonder why the server isn't responding to any of the requests.  Maybe it is another problem besides Apache??

I am fairly confident that Apache is the culprit and cause of the slowdown, yet I am not experienced enough to know how to research this further.

Any further advice on troubleshooting steps I should take would be help.